# How do I set transaction level on io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLPool

Tags: mysql, kotlin, vert.x

Hi I have the following python code:

```
self.db_client.execute("SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED")
self.db_client.execute(query, args)
```

I am already using  io.vertx.mysqlclient.MySQLPool in java/kotlin and I would like to add "TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL" ability to my execute query.
I am not sure if it makes sense to just add it to the query that I am running?
for example this code:

```
private val pool: MySQLPool

init {
    logger.info(
        "Building MySqlClient with host: [${connectOptions.host}], " +
            "port: [${connectOptions.port}], " +
            "db user: [${connectOptions.user}], poolSize: ${poolOptions.maxSize}"
    )
    pool = MySQLPool.pool(vertx, connectOptions, poolOptions)
}
fun executeQuery(query: String, args: List<Any>): Future<RowSet<Row>> {
    logger.debug("Execute the following query: [$query] with args [$args] on [${connectOptions.host}]")
    // Get a connection from the pool
    return pool.getConnection()
        .compose { connection ->
            // Set the transaction isolation level on the connection
            val isolationLevelQuery = "SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED"
            connection.query(isolationLevelQuery).execute()
                .compose { _ ->
                    // Execute your actual query
                    connection.preparedQuery(query).execute(Tuple.tuple(args))
                }
                .eventually { _ ->
                    // Close the connection when done
                    connection.close()
                }
        }
}
```

1. How do I know that I do using ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED?
2. Does it make sense to add it like that, what is the best practice for such customizations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have it right. `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL whatever` is its own SQL statement. It sets the state of the current database connection so future queries use it.

Be careful with `READ UNCOMMITTED`. It can return inconsistent results.

**Edit** These transaction levels are about consistency of results for queries within a single connection in the face of concurrency.  [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)'s default transaction isolation is `REPEATABLE READ`. `READ COMMITTED` is a little cheaper because `REPEATABLE READ` creates snapshots that last the duration of a transaction.

You ask whether it makes sense to relax the isolation level. It's not possible to give a definitive answer without knowing, in detail, what problem you hope to solve.

You ask how to test this. That's a hard question to answer in the abstract, especially because the purpose of isolation levels is to prevent relatively rare race conditions under heavy concurrent workloads. This sort of thing is difficult to test without a production workload on your system. You'll have to think through the use cases that push you to change the isolation level. When you relax it do you get better performance, especially with long-lived transactions?

I have used `READ UNCOMMITTED` for bulk queries for historical reporting on active tables, to avoid the cost of any snapshot. I knew it worked because deadlocks and long delays vanished from other connections' transactional workloads. It took a day or two of observing a production system's logs to convince myself of that. But I also knew I might get inconsistent results when reading active rows. Historical reporting on my data didn't involve active rows so I could get away with it.

Comment: But any idea how can I test it?